# PSTN issue. No dial tone for modem

Tags: telephony, modem

I am having an issue with a pstn line connecting to a modem. The modem can not get a dial tone but when I plug in a normal telephone it can. 
What are the troubleshooting steps for this and potential fixes?
Would a line filter do any good and

**Is there such a thing as a repeater for PSTN?** or will a DSL filter help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a DSL modem? If it is you might want a filter.

1. Check the port on the modem, verify there is no damage.
2. Try the modem with a different phone line, in the same building(same number)
3. Try the modem with a different phone line, in a different building(different number)

Answer (score 1):

Try issuing a reset to the modem from your terminal program:

AT&F

then try to dial a number:

ATDT8005551234

Some common AT commands are here:
[AT command reference](http://www.computerhope.com/atcom.htm)